# copy web informations in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C so please explain your answers as much as you can :)

What i would like to do is this:

i want to create in C a program that goes to a specific site and copies certain data to a txt file from where i can analyze them.

The question is how i copy these informations?
is this something that can be done in C?(if yes tell me the library that i have to use  or the code)

for example i want to make my program do this:

go to this site - copy the lines(1-10)

thanx for your help

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Take a look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl) for the retrieving part of the problem.

Comment: It seems like you want to write a web crawler. There are good existing frameworks, but not in C. You may want to try http://scrapy.org/ for instance.

Comment: My mistake...I should read About before asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `curl  link to the webpage -o file`  or `wget link to page` in your program with `system()`,

But by default you will get HTML source of page.   From that you can copy your required info.

if your link is a text file [like this](http://livechat.rediff.com/sports/score/score.txt)
Then it will fetches as it is. Then you can open that file with `fopen()`.read first ten lines with `fgets()`. copy into another file.

you can also use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) library